# Use Azure webjobs and queue storage to execute at a given time

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

My goal is to push a message to the Azure queue, and have the webjob handle it at a given time. E.g. { message : "remember the milk", time: 2016-02-10-10:10:00}

I could do this naively by dequeueing the message, check the timestamp, and put it back on the queue if the time has not come.

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this in the Azure world?

Comment: To add on what Peter answered, keep in mind that the max initialVisibilityDelay is of 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the initialVisibilityDelay:

```
[DoesServiceRequestAttribute]
public void AddMessage(
    CloudQueueMessage message,
    Nullable<TimeSpan> timeToLive = null,
    Nullable<TimeSpan> initialVisibilityDelay = null,
    QueueRequestOptions options = null,
    OperationContext operationContext = null
)
```

The message will be visible when the delay timeouts:

> initialVisibilityDelay
>   Type: System.Nullable
>   A TimeSpan specifying the interval of time from now during which the message will be invisible. If null then the message will be visible immediately.

MSDN: [microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage.aspx)